# Prevent Edge from closing DevTools on each page reload

Tags: microsoft-edge

Everytime i refresh the page, Edge closes it's DevTools.
I also check "Preserve logs" option from DevTools, but it is unchecked when i reopen.

How can i prevent this useless browser from closing DevTools everytime?

Edit: i've also tried https://github.com/Microsoft/edge-diagnostics-adapter and is as useless as their browser.

Comment: i got the same issue, did you find a solution back then?

Comment: nope, hopefully this browser ended up being deprecated.